# Atuomatically Picture capturing from Android phone after detecting a face

Tags: android, opencv

I managed to run the **OpenCV** face detection sample on **Android Studio** and I want now to take a picture automatically after it detects faces. Since there are not that much answers online please any one knows how to do it? are there any tutorials which I can use. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take photo using Camera API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829223/how-to-take-photo-using-camera-api)

Comment: It dosen't work in my case. Thanks

Comment: [Create a method of Taking pictures with the camera and When it will detect faces call that method. here you will find the code for Taking pictures with the camera on Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421694/taking-pictures-with-camera-on-android-programmatically)